# How do I grep recursively in files with a certain extension?

Tags: grep, find

To find all file paths with `.out` extension in subdirectories,  I use

```
find . -name '*.out'
```

To grep a pattern in all files ending in `.out`, I use

```
grep pattern *.out
```

How do I combine these two commands, so that it finds all files and then greps in those files?

I am looking for an elegant alternative to

```
grep -r 'pattern' . | grep '.out'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` allows you to run a program on each file it finds using the `-exec` option:

```
find -name '*.out' -exec grep -H pattern {} \;
```

`{}` indicates the file name, and `;` tells `find` that that's the end of the arguments to `grep`. `-H` tells `grep` to always print the file name, which it normally does only when there are multiple files to process.

Comment: This works, but I want the file name listed too.

Comment: Grep -H will do that. Added it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `globstar`, if your shell is Bash version 4+:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep pattern **/*.out
```

From [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will
>   match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If
>   the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories
>   match.